# Spring Security multiple dao authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC project and I have 2 modes of login, one is for a single person and other for a group login. The single person or personal login works now, but I want to implement group functionality. As the database model for group is different, I have implemented it in another database table.

There is only one way user can login. Now in backend, I would like to check if the user is logging for his personal account or the group account(unique usernames). I would like to know how to implement multiple dao authentication methods in the XML and redirect based upon the login. Both the models implement UserDetails interface. Here is the security-context.xml

```
    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/canvas/list" always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp" />
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
           <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
               <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Person model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{
   @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen",sequenceName = "person_seq")
    private int id;
// Other stuff
}
```

GroupMembers model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupaccount")
public class GroupMembers implements UserDetails {

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_GROUP");

    @Id
    @Column(name="memberid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "groupmembers_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupmembers_seq_gen",sequenceName = "groupmembers_seq")
    private Long groupId;
//other stuff
}
```

LoginServiceImpl :

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private PersonDAO personDAO;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(username.toLowerCase());
            if(person == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");} //Never specify which one was it exactly
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
    }
}
```

Assembler :

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(Person userEntity){
        String username = userEntity.getUsername().toLowerCase();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();

        // Long id = userEntity.getId();
        boolean enabled = userEntity.isEnabled();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        User user = new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        return  user;
        }
}
```

Do I need one more LoginServiceImpl and assembler? How do I define the beans in security-application-context.xml for multiple dao entry points. Any pointers are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need separate `LoginServiceImpl` and `Assembler` because you are doing two kinds of authentication with different `Entity` classes user and group.

Even more, you'll need different `AuthenticationProvider` and `UserDetailsService` for user and group login:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="userLoginAuthenticationProvider" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="groupLoginAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- user login -->
<beans:bean id="userLoginAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- group login -->
<beans:bean id="groupLoginAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="GroupLoginServiceImpl"/>
       <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
</beans:bean>
```

You have to implement `GroupLoginServiceImpl` that calls a repository method on your group repository.

Please take a look into this [demo project](https://github.com/ksokol/spring-sandbox/tree/security-multiple-dao/spring-mvc). It contains authentication with varying `UserDetailService`s depending on the submitted login name.
It also contains a redirect to a personal or group page depending on a specific authority attached to the authentication. Just type `mvn tomcat:run` and browse to `http://localhost:8080/sandbox`. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a GroupLoginServiceImpl that has implemented loadByUserName(), but if you check the main post for latest error... Thank you very much.

Comment: @we-are-borg I'm not sure but I don't see latest error in your post. Do you modified `authentication-manager` in your security xml as I suggested?

Comment: I have added another post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041310/error-creating-bean-with-name-authenticationmanager.. I am making the modifications u suggested now.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, didn't work , can you check if this xml is correct, http://pastebin.com/GFK3V5Qd ... Thanks

Comment: `authenticationManagerForPersonal` and `authenticationManagerForGroup` are of bean type `ProviderManager`. This is wrong. You have to declare those beans as type `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.
Please take a closer look at my spring security configuration.

Comment: Yes, I changed that, its in the latest pastebin...I guess you saw the old pastebin.. . http://pastebin.com/GFK3V5Qd  ...Still there are problems...I have posted complete xml and error log...

Comment: I'm busy right now. I will set up a demo application and share it with you.

Comment: When you do it, please note, I want to use 2 database tables for authentication depending upon url. Thanks a lot... :-)

Comment: If incase you know how to distinguish between the logged in user, for example, if I try to get the currentlyAuthenticatedUser, then depending upon which login he has used, the Object type will be either Person or GroupMember, how can I get which login the user used so I can properly redirect to the necessary page.

Comment: Please take a look into this [demo project](https://github.com/ksokol/spring-sandbox/tree/security-multiple-dao/spring-mvc). It contains authentication with varying `UserDetailService`s depending on the submitted login name.
It also contains a redirect to a personal or group page depending on a specific authority attached to the authentication. Just type `mvn tomcat:run` and browse to `http://localhost:8080/sandbox`. Good luck

Comment: Can you please tell me what it means by a specific authority attached to the authentication, In the code you gave me, on the login page you have  <p>login with user/user or group/group</p>. Is this some sort of radio button or something to specify for which account user wants to login. P.S : User can have same email id as username in both accounts.

Comment: Take a look into the `(Personal|Group)Assembler`. You'll find an additional role `GROUP_LOGIN` and `USER_LOGIN`, respectively. These roles are used by `RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to decide which view user should see. There is no radio button in this example. This is a different requirement you didn't mention earlier and requires a different solution in Spring Security.

Comment: Ok, I have almost developed a solution with the radio button thing, where custom url of /j_spring_security_check_for_person and /j_spring_security_check_for_group I have implemented, can you please check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041310/error-creating-bean-with-name-authenticationmanager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69279/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-ksokol).

Comment: Hi Man, I am logged into chat... Will wait for you... Thanks... :-)