# Error creating bean with name AuthenticationManager

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application which uses Spring-Security. In the application for login I have to use 2 login url's

- /j_spring_security_check_for_person
             AND
- /j_spring_security_check_for_group

Both the login url's check against the database where I have implemented UserDetails and userDetailsService. To connect these both url's for login, I am using springSecurityFilterChain. Unfortunately, it is not working. I am at this problem since 2 days, I might be making some silly mistake. Kindly check the log and xml,

Error Log :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:28)
    at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:20)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
```

security-application-context.xml

```
<security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true"
               auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/canvas/list"
               always-use-default-target="false"  authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp" />
<security:logout logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
                     invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
</security:http>



<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="authenticationProcessingFilterForPersonal, authenticationProcessingFilterForGroup"/>
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>


    <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterForPersonal"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManagerForPersonal"/>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check_for_person" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterForGroup"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManagerForGroup"/>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check_for_group"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="authenticationManagerForPersonal" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                    <property name="userDetailsService">
                        <ref bean="userDetailsService"/>
                    </property>
                    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="authenticationManagerForGroup" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                    <property name="userDetailsService">
                        <ref bean="groupDetailsService"/>
                    </property>
                    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationManagerForPersonal"/>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationManagerForGroup"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>
```

If I replace the authentication-manager code with the below snippet, I don't get an error, but the 2 login url's are not registered :

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
                <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
            </security:authentication-provider>
            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="groupDetailsService">
                <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
            </security:authentication-provider>
        </security:authentication-manager>-->
```

Comment: P.S : I have LoginServiceImpl which has userDetails and GroupLoginServiceImpl which has groupDetailsService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authenticationManagerForPersonal` and `authenticationManagerForGroup` are of bean type `ProviderManager`. This is wrong. You have to declare those beans as type `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.
Please take a closer look at my [spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020280/spring-security-multiple-dao-authentication/28034659) configuration.

Comment: Yes, I have done that as indicated in the old post, here is the latest pastebin : http://pastebin.com/GFK3V5Qd

Answer (score 0):

As the exception message indicates, your `authenticationManagerForGroup` and `authenticationManagerForPersonal` are configured invalidly. As discoverable from the type signature and JavaDoc, `ProviderManager` takes a list of `AuthenticationManager` as constructor argument, but you configure the `AuthenticationManager`s as property arguments.

You should be able to get this working by replacing the `<property name="providers">` element with `<constructor-arg>`.

Comment: That didn't help. Thank you though.